# Powershell IP address

Tags: powershell

Requesting some ideas on modifying below PS script. Currently I have to manually change the first 3 octets of the IP address in line 37 to the IP's of the location that this script is being deployed to. Was checking if someone knows a way I could modify script so I don't have to manually change the first three octets, last octet will always be 1-60.  Version of PS on host systems is 2.0

```
Function Check-Patches{
Param($Filename)

    $logname = "C:\temp\PatchVerify\$FileName.csv"
    [xml]$x = Get-Content "C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\$FileName.mbsa"

    $PatchStatus = @()

    #This list is created based on a text file that is provided.
    $monthlyPatches = Get-Content "C:\Temp\PatchVerify\Patches_NA.txt" | ? {$_ -match "-KB(?<KB>\d+)"} | % { $matches.KB}


    #Create objects for all the patches in the updatelog that were in the monthly list.
    Switch ( $x | % {$_.SecScan} | % {$_.Check} | ? {$_.id -eq 500} | % {$_.detail} | % {$_.updatedata} | ? {$monthlyPatches -contains $_.KBID} )
    {
        {$_.isinstalled -eq "true"}
                {
                    $PatchStatus += New-Object PsObject -property @{Device=$FileName; Patch=$_.KBID; Present="YES"}
                    Continue
                }
        {$_.isinstalled -eq "false"}
                {
                    $PatchStatus += New-Object PsObject -property @{Device=$FileName; Patch=$_.KBID; Present="NO"}
                    Continue
                }
    }

    $detectedPatches = $PatchStatus | % {$_.Patch}
    #Populate all of the monthly patches that weren't found on the machine as installed or failed
    $monthlypatches | ? {$detectedPatches -notcontains $_} | % { $PatchStatus += New-Object PsObject -property @{Device=$FileName; Patch=$_; Present="Unknown"} }

    #Output results
    $PatchStatus

    }

1..60 | % { Check-Patches "172.26.210.$_" } | Export-Csv "C:\temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: No, i doubt you have to manually modify it. That being said. What are you changing it to? Do you have a list? You could import a text file and loop though each subnet defined?

Comment: The IP's change from site to site the one listed in script is what I'm using in a test environment. You have an example of a text file that it could loop through each subnet?

Comment: Really, I answered your question already. You should accept the answer and post a new question. But for your new question, about getting the other patches in the CSV, you should show a sample of what the contents of that Patches_NA.txt file looks like so we know what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a WMI call to get the local IP, and do a RegEx replace to get the first three octets. This replaces the last .### with nothing to get just the first three octets.

```
$localip = @(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE'")[0].ipaddress[0] -replace "\.\d+$"
1..60 | % { Check-Patches "$localip.$_" } | Export-Csv "C:\temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It looks like i didnt read well again. This is the correct answer. I though the script would be run against different subnets from one location.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the input.  This solution is working great however the .csv file should be showing "Unknown" for these devices and they are all showing "Yes".

Comment: That's not a problem with my answer to your question, that has to do with how you're checking patches.

Comment: Thanks, figured out why I was getting those results I commented out line 7 and that corrected the issue.  Any suggestion on how I can get the script to read line 7 and populate results in the .csv file?

Comment: I'm confused, line seven is '$patchstatus = @()' in you code shown. It's there updated code that you can post in your question?

Comment: Below is the updated code I'm working with, There's file located in

Comment: Please edit your answer, don't try to post code updates in comments

Comment: Below is the updated code I'm working with, There's a file located in C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\$env:ComputerName.mbsa (host sytem)  that will contain a list of pathches listed in the Patches_NA.txt file. I'm just trying to figure out a way that info can also be exported to .csv file

Comment: I took out this line [xml]$x = Get-Content "C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\$env:ComputerName.mbsa" because it was causing another issue.   I added these two lines at the end $monthlyPatches = Get-Content "C:\Temp\PatchVerify\Patches_NA.txt" | ? {$_ -match "-KB(?<KB>\d+)"} | % { $matches.KB}
    Get-Content  { Check-Patches "$monthlyPatches" }  "C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\$env:ComputerName.mbsa"  | Export-Csv "C:\temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Trying to figure out a way to get the patch info from C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\$env:ComputerName.mbsa to .csv file.  Since I can't post entire code hope that makes since.

Comment: your code is very hard to read in comments. Please, go up to your Question that you posted, click Edit at the bottom of it, and try again there where you can format things to be readable.

Comment: I went up to question I posted and edited script that's currently what I'm working with.  There is one file that also needs to have data extracted to .csv located in C:\Users\Cambridge\SecurityScans\%computername%.mbsa   I'm testing a few other options let me know if you have idea or need more info on what I'm tying to do.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a text file with the following contents

```
10.10.13
10.10.14
10.10.15
```

Those are some internal subnets. Putting your last statement in a loop you would get something like this

```
Get-Content c:\pathtotext\subnets.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $subnet = $_
    1..60 | % { Check-Patches "$subnet.$_" } | Export-Csv "C:\temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

You read the contents of the file and for each line in the file run your statement. The assignment `$subnet = $_` is required since another pipe `1..60 |` is called which would change the data in `$_`

Comment: Ok, this may work. You just gave me idea on this let me try it out and will get back to you.  Thanks.